# Check numbers are in range of each other

Tags: javascript, math

I am writing a javascript app and have 3 user selected numbers, Im stuck with a way of figuring out weather the numbers are all within plus and minus 5 of each other.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Do you have some code you can share?

Comment: No Im really stuck with this one, Trying to figure out the maths more than the code.

Comment: can you please give one example , how exactly you want ?

Comment: Ok so say I have 3 random numbers "35", "32", "38" I need to check if all 3 numbers are within + and - 5 of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't sure if the difference between the lowest and the highest number had to be within 5, or if all numbers had to be. Since @Banana-In-Black had one solution covered, I went the other way:

This makes sure that there isn't more than 5 between each number (not just lowest and highest)

```
var withinFive = function(num1, num2, num3) {
    var diff1 = Math.abs(num1 - num2);
    var diff2 = Math.abs(num2 - num3);

    return (diff1 <= 5 && diff2 <=5);
};

console.log(withinFive(1,2,7));
```

so in this example `{1,2} is <= 5` and `{2,7} <= 5` so the function returns true

Answer (score 2):

```
function(num1, num2, num3) {
    var array = [num1, num2, num3];
    array.sort();
    return Math.abs(array[0] - array[array.length - 1]) <= 5;
}
```

[Edit*] Another improved version if i misunderstand ur purpose:

```
function calculate() {
    var array = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        // put every argument in a array
        array.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    // sorting in ascending order
    array.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
    var interval = array.length - 1;
    // math part
    return Math.abs(array[0] - array[interval]) <= interval * 5;
}

ex: calculate(4, 15, 7); // you'll get false
    calculate(6, 10, 9, 16); // true
```

Comment: 5 is a difference between each other, so in this code it should be <= 10 I guess because there are 3 numbers instead of 2?

Comment: Some explanations would go a long way here... We want to educate users here and "make the internet a better place", not just provide copy-pasta...

Comment: @Lix I actually educated while reading this code. Op should do the same :) it's not some cryptic code

Comment: Not everyone reading this post will be able to understand this. We should try to cater for the all users.

Comment: Simply explaining that by sorting the array we are now able to only check the fist and last elements is not too intuitive... I'm not saying that it needs a full line by line breakdown, but just a note regarding the logic would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your time Banana-In-Black, The solution below from jasonscript worked but I appreciate your help.